# HTML Click event inside setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, client-side

I want to call click() for a given id inside setInterval

```
setInterval(function(){
document.getElementById('test').click();
}, 10);
```

This click() is working for a tag by clicking from another tag. But not working when I am just calling it in setInterval or even calling the same line in script. Any way I can achieve this ?

**Jquery click is also not working neither any trigger call.**

```
setInterval(function(){
$('#test').trigger('click');
}, 10);
```

Here is the complete code for testing:-

```html
<html>
<body>

 <p>Select a File to Load:</p>
 <input id="inputFileToLoad" type="file" onchange="loadImageFileAsURL();" />
 <a id="testy" href="" onclick="document.getElementById('inputFileToLoad').click(); return false">Upload</a>
 <br />

<script type='text/javascript'>

function loadImageFileAsURL()
{
 alert("Its a Test");
}
setTimeout(function(){
 document.getElementById('testy').click();
}, 1000);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How about posting a complete code example so that we can reproduce the issue?

Comment: Sorry Actually I typed the sample code directly here. Just a spelling mistake. :) I edited the question.

Comment: I added the complete code for test. Please help :(

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** (check console)

```js
setInterval(function(){
    $('#test').trigger('click');
}, 10);

$(document).on('click', '#test', function() {
  console.log('clicked');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">test</div>
```

Comment: OP: _"Jquery click is also not working neither any trigger call."_ Since this question is lacking crucial information, it can't be answered yet. -1

Comment: I added the whole HTML code. You can check it now :)